# A quick question on AR(1) model

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

Consider an AR(1) model given by

$$X_t=\phi_1X_{t-1}+a_t.$$

AR(1) is stationary tells that all variance and mean of $X$ at any time $t$ should be the same. However, the conditional mean

$$E(X_{t+k}\mid X_t=x_t)=\phi_1^k x_t$$

that indicates the conditional mean is changing with time. Then how this violates the stationarity of $X_t$?

How a stationary random variable becomes not stationary when it comes to conditional?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: use a more informative title.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, please consider, accepting/upvoting it.

Answer (score 2):

The correct definition of stationarity is this:

A process is said to be weakly stationary if both the unconditional mean and the autocovariances do not depend on $t$.

Now, for the first-order autoregression process $X_t = c+\phi X_{t-1}+a_t$, where $a_t$ is white noise with variance $\sigma^2$, the unconditional expected value is

$$\mu_0 = E(X_t) = c/(1-\phi).$$

Furthermore, the unconditional variance is
$$
\gamma_0 = \sigma^2/(1-\phi^2),
$$
and the $j$th autocovariance is
$$
\gamma_j = [\phi^j/(1-\phi^2)]\sigma^2.
$$
Thus, since neither the unconditional mean $\mu_0$ nor the autocovariances $\gamma_j$ depend on $t$, we conclude that AR(1) is stationary, provided $|\phi| < 1$.

Comment: I think I'm confused with the conditional mean and variance. Assuiming that we run the model, giving an initial $X_1=x_1$, the variance of $X_t$ will change for different $t$, given that initial condition. But if we look at each individual $X_t$ the mean and variance does not change, how can that happen?

Comment: Alternative to unconditional is marginal. To obtain the distribution of $X_t$ you have to integrate the past observations. The fact that unconditional mean and variance do not depend on $t$ is due to the gaussian random noise assumption.

Comment: I understand from math point but still kinda confused. Let's say that for an AR1 model since $X_t$ is stationary, then $E[X_t]=E[X_{t-1}]$. Now run the model from initial $X_1=x_1$, we have $E[X_t]\neq E[X_{t-1}]$. My question is why does that happen

Comment: I see. I think the best way to answer your doubt is to go through the computations of the expectations. In the case of AR(1), the best way to compute $E(X_t)$ is to see AR(1) as an $MA(\infty)$.

Comment: @Maskoff - I think the point is that you do not start at a fixed $X_t$ but imagine the process has run infinite often by the time $t$ or at least enough times that you are close enough to $X_t \sim N( \mu_0, \gamma_0)$